# Arduino Communication with unity using C# through UDP scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, udp

I want to communicate with arduino using UDP through unity 3D. I found a script online and my task is to read the command from unity and activate a LED or some other component through arduino.

I have this script but i don't know why it isn't working. Am new to C# so please kindly help me out.

The Script

```
//UDP-Send
//-----------------------
// [url]http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979228.aspx#ID0E3BAC[/url]

// > gesendetes unter
// 127.0.0.1 : 8050 empfangen

// nc -lu 127.0.0.1 8050
//*/
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPsend : MonoBehaviour
{   
    private static int localPort;

    // prefs
    private string IP;  // define in init
    public int port;  // define in init

    // "connection" things
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    UdpClient client;

    // gui
    //string strMessage="";

    // call it from shell (as program)
    private static void Main()
    {
        UDPsend sendObj=new UDPsend();
        sendObj.init();

        // testing via console
        // sendObj.inputFromConsole();

        // as server sending endless
        sendObj.sendEndless(" endless infos \n");

    }
    // start from unity3d
    public void Start()
    {
        init();
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,380,200,400);
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPSend-Data\n172.16.28.255 "+port+" #\n"
            + "shell> nc -lu 172.16.28.255  "+port+" \n"
            ,style);

        // ------------------------
        // send it
        // ------------------------
        strMessage=GUI.TextField(new Rect(40,420,140,20),strMessage);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(190,420,40,20),"send"))
        {
            sendString(strMessage+"\n");
        }      
    } 

    // init
    public void init()
    {
        //Define endpoint
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define
        //IP="127.0.0.1";
        IP = "172.16.28.255";
        port=8888;

        // ----------------------------
        // Send
        // ----------------------------
        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        client = new UdpClient();

        // status
        print("Sending to "+IP+" : "+port);
        print("Testing: nc -lu "+IP+" : "+port);

    }

    // inputFromConsole
    private void inputFromConsole()
    {
        try
        {
            string text;
            do
            {
                text = Console.ReadLine();

                // Den Text zum Remote-Client senden.
                if (text != "")
                {
                    //UTF8 coding
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                    //send data to client
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                }
            } while (text != "");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }

    // sendData
    private void sendString(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            //if (message != "")
            //{
            //UTF8 coding
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            //send data
            client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
            sendString(strMessage+"\n");
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }

    // endless test
    private void sendEndless(string testStr)
    {
        do
        {
            sendString(testStr);
        }
        while(true);

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `isn't working` doesn't help much. What firmware code is running on the Arduino? The IP address `172.16.28.255` seems fishy, is it a broadcast address? What hardware is on the Arduino so that he has network access, what IP does the Arduino have?

Comment: yes it is broadcast and and with arduino I am using ethernet shield and it's ip is 172.16.28.118

Comment: Then hook up your Arduino to your PC via USB and start debug the firmware (also, **post the firmware**). See if it actually receives any data and what it tries to send out. And the exact procedure what you do, and what the Unity clients sends via UDP. There are lots of factors and unknowns here without which your question cannot be answered.

Comment: i have tried controllng the arduino through mobile app and it works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe add firewall exception for the unity application to be able to send UDP traffic?

Comment: the code has no errors?

Comment: I can't tell if the code has any errors if you do not post the arduino firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I once had to do something similar, where I connected a raspberry pi web service to an unity game, it wasn't UDP though, but http can be quite fast if the packets are small enough.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playercontroller : MonoBehaviour {

public string url; //FIXME hardcoded URL
public string coordinates = "{0,0}";
private string previouscoordinates = "{0,0}";
public WWW mycoord;
private bool previouslyDone = true;

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (previouslyDone) {
        previouslyDone = false;
        Debug.Log("sending HTTP request! to:");
        Debug.Log(url);
        mycoord = new WWW(url);
    } else if (mycoord.isDone) {
        Debug.Log("Got response!"); 
        if(mycoord.text.Length > 4) {
            coordinates = mycoord.text;
        }
        Debug.Log(coordinates);
        previouslyDone = true;
    }
    if (previouscoordinates != coordinates) {
        string x = "";
        string y = "";
        int index = 1;
        char nextchar = '0';
        while (nextchar != ',') {
            x += coordinates [index];
            index++;
            nextchar = coordinates [index];
        }
        index++;
        while (nextchar != '}') {
            y += coordinates [index];
            index++;
            nextchar = coordinates [index];
        }
        float newX = 0 + (float.Parse (x) * 2);
        float newZ = 0 - (float.Parse (y) * 2);
        transform.position = new Vector3 (newX, 1.5f, newZ);
        previouscoordinates = coordinates;
    } else {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal / 10, 0.0f, moveVertical / 10);
        transform.position = transform.position + movement;
    }
```

the part you're looking for is:

```
    mycoord = new WWW(url);
```

this initiates an async http-request since this was called every frame, I waited for

```
    mycoord.isDone
```

before I could fetch the data (mycoord.text, which is a String)

so basically you create a request (WWW myrequest());
wait for it to be done (myrequest.isDone) and then fetch the result (myrequest.text).

for the arduino side just use:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer

hope this helps.